# extract php array value

Tags: php, arrays, extract

I have the following array (exposed using var_dump).

```
array (size=3)
    'auth' => string 'debug' (length=5)
    'url' => string 'http://X.X.X.X/status.cgi?' (length=31)
    'page' => string '{ "host": {   "uptime": 1543,     "time": "2011-07-26 12:07:40",  "fwversion": "v1.1.1",  "hostname": "ASDASDASD",    "netrole": "DFDFDF"  },  "lan": {   "status": [{ "plugged": 1, "speed": 100, "duplex": 1 }],    "hwaddr": "00:00:22:11:11:11",  "ip": "",   "rx": { "bytes": 5988, "packets": 83, "errors": 0 },    "tx": { "bytes": 9496, "packets": 120, "errors": 0 }  },  "wan": {  "status": [],   "hwaddr": "00:00:00:00:00:00",  "ip": "",   "rx": { "bytes": 0, "packets": 0, "errors": 0 },    "tx": { "bytes": 0, "packets"'... (length=1779)
```

I need to extract info from WAN like ip or rx...

I have tried using $array['page']['wan']['rx'] but nothing!!!

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `print_r(...)` with the second argument `$return = true`:
`<?php
$b = array ('m' => 'monkey', 'foo' => 'bar', 'x' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
$results = print_r($b, true); // $results now contains output from print_r
?>`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 3):

The `page` value of your `$array` is not actually an array, but a string. Since it's a JSON string, you should use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode the string into a meaningful format for PHP to handle:

```
$page = json_decode($array['page']);
$pageArray = json_decode($array['page']); // Returned as an array
```

And to get the RX for example:

```
var_dump($page->wan->rx); // Returned as an object
var_dump($pageArray['wan']['rx']); // Return as an array
```

Comment: If you prefer to decode your JSON into an associative array rather than an object, you can use `json_decode($array['page'], true);`